# Summarize and count unique values of a column based on the values of another column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below

```
name<-c("Jack","Bob","Jack","Bill","Jack","Bob")
items<-c("car","house","ball","desk","bike","chair")
d<-data.frame(name,item)

name  items
1 Jack   car
2  Bob house
3 Jack  ball
4 Bill  desk
5 Jack  bike
6  Bob chair
```

and I want to convert it to a dataframe in which the unique `items` will be summarized based on the `name` and a new column will be added with their count, so it will be like:

```
name         items count
1 Jack car,ball,bike     3
2  Bob   house,chair     2
3 Bill         chair     1
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to have a comma separated sequence of items? Is this data frame going to be displayed? According to tidyverse principles, it's generally not a good idea to have multiple elements per cell

Comment: no comma is not needed but I had to show that I want words to be separated. because I will need to further select and process them later

Comment: If you're going to further select and process the data, I really recommend against placing multiple items in a cell (see https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not convinced that a comma-separated sequence is the best way to approach further data processing, here is code that does what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(count = n(),
            items = toString(items)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  count items          
  <chr> <int> <chr>          
1 Bill      1 desk           
2 Bob       2 house, chair   
3 Jack      3 car, ball, bike
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution without extra packages

```r
d <-data.frame(name  = c("Jack","Bob","Jack","Bill","Jack","Bob"),
               items = c("car","house","ball","desk","bike","chair"))
```

Get the frequencies for `names` and add another column for the concatenated `items`.

```r
result <- margin.table(table(d), 1)
sdf <- data.frame(items = paste(d$items[d$name == names(result)], collapse = ", "), result)
```

reorder columns

```r
sdf <- sdf[, c(2, 1, 3)]
sdf
#>   name             items Freq
#> 1 Bill house, ball, desk    1
#> 2  Bob house, ball, desk    2
#> 3 Jack house, ball, desk    3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
d %>% group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(foo = paste0(items, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  mutate(count_w = length(foo)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-items) %>% 
  distinct()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name foo   count_w
  <chr> <chr>          <int>
1 Jack  car,ball,bike      3
2 Bob   house,chair        2
3 Bill  desk               1
```